# Define text color based on value using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So basically my AsyncTask get the value from the url and when i execute i wanna show green text or red text if contains ("-").
I have search around and none of the option worked for me. i do have a RecyclerView.ViewHolder but don't know how to incorporate before i execute. Everything works, except the colors.
Thank you in advance

**Activity**

````
public class BTCData extends AsyncTask<Void,RecyclerView.ViewHolder,Void> {
    String data = "";
    String dataParsed1h ="";
    String dataParsed24h ="";
    String dataParsed7d ="";
    String percent_change_1h = "";
    String percent_change_24h = "";
    String percent_change_7d = "";
    Activity activity;
    List<Model> items;

    public BTCData() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL ("https://...");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (java.net.HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while (line != null){
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data+line;
            }

            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);
            for(int i=0 ;i< JA.length(); i++){
                JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
                percent_change_1h =  "1H  " + JO.getString("percent_change_1h") + "%";
                percent_change_24h = "24H  " + JO.getString("percent_change_24h") + "%";
                percent_change_7d = "7D  " + JO.getString("percent_change_7d") + "%" ;

                dataParsed1h = dataParsed1h + percent_change_1h;
                dataParsed24h = dataParsed24h + percent_change_7d;
                dataParsed7d = dataParsed7d + percent_change_24h;


            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        MainActivity.btc_percent_change_1h.setText(this.dataParsed1h);
        MainActivity.btc_percent_change_24h.setText(this.dataParsed24h);
        MainActivity.btc_percent_change_7d.setText(this.dataParsed7d);
    }
}```

**View Holder**
````

```
public class CoinAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

Adapter adapter;
boolean isLoading;
Activity activity;
List<Model> items;

int visibleThreshold = 5,lastVisibleItem, totalItemcount;

public void setAdapter(Adapter adapter) {
    this.adapter = adapter;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity)
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_main,parent,false);
    return new CoinViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Model item = items.get(position);
    CoinViewHolder holderItem = (CoinViewHolder)holder;

    holderItem.btc_percent_change_1h.setTextColor(item.getPercentage_change_1h().contains("-")?
            Color.parseColor("#FF0000"):Color.parseColor("#32CD32"));
    holderItem.btc_percent_change_24h.setTextColor(item.getPercentage_change_24h().contains("-")?
            Color.parseColor("#FF0000"):Color.parseColor("#32CD32"));
    holderItem.btc_percent_change_7d.setTextColor(item.getPercentage_change_7d().contains("-")?
            Color.parseColor("#FF0000"):Color.parseColor("#32CD32"));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}
public void setLoader() {isLoading = true;}
public void updateData (List<Model> models)
{
    this.items = models;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

```
**on Activity**


    public static TextView btc_percent_change_1h;
    public static TextView btc_percent_change_24h;
    public static TextView btc_percent_change_7d;



//Percentage
        btc_percent_change_1h = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btc_percent_change_1h);
        btc_percent_change_24h = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btc_percent_change_24h);
        btc_percent_change_7d = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btc_percent_change_7d);


and finally call...

BTCData process = new BTCData();
        process.execute();
```

[image: Green times but red if negative value]

Comment: Please add mainactivity code as well and more specifically your code where and how you are instantiating your adapter stuff. This will help to figure out the actual problem.

Comment: Return the result from `doInBackground` method of `AsyncTask`. Then, get those return values in `onPostExecute`. Pass the result values from `onPostExecute` to the view where you want.
Got it ?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed on Main Activity i simply call `BTCData process = new BTCData();
                            process.execute();`

Comment: @MuhammadAwais you mean return value to viewholder and than return them to `onPostexecute`? I thought of that but don't know how.

Comment: jonh :: currently, you're implementation return void from `doInBackground` function. `doInBackground` should return the results which you got from API. Result which is returned from `doInBackground`, is received in `onPostExecute`. From `onPostExecute` function, you can pass the values to any other view.
Check the documentation from link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: @MuhammadAwais the code works fine. i got the values where i want. But i want to give color. (green for positive and red for negative). so if i could put the `hoderItem` together with the `AsyncTask` code, it would be perfect.

Comment: @jonhbishop as you said, red text if contains ("-"), but when `green text`?

Comment: @rahat green text and red if have "-"

Comment: There is no code for recyclerview where adapter is attached to it?

Comment: @rahat `public TextView dataParsed1h, dataParsed24h,dataParsed7d;
    public CoinViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super (itemView);


        dataParsed1h = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btc_percent_change_1h);
        dataParsed24h = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btc_percent_change_24h);
        dataParsed7d = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btc_percent_change_7d);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe is not the best option, but it works

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(CoinAdapter aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        MainActivity.btc_percent_change_1h.setTextColor((this.dataParsed1h.contains("-")?
                Color.parseColor("#FF0000"):Color.parseColor("#32CD32")));
        MainActivity.btc_percent_change_1h.setText(this.dataParsed1h);
        MainActivity.btc_percent_change_24h.setTextColor((this.dataParsed24h.contains("-")?
                Color.parseColor("#FF0000"):Color.parseColor("#32CD32")));
        MainActivity.btc_percent_change_24h.setText(this.dataParsed24h);
        MainActivity.btc_percent_change_7d.setTextColor((this.dataParsed7d.contains("-")?
                Color.parseColor("#FF0000"):Color.parseColor("#32CD32")));
        MainActivity.btc_percent_change_7d.setText(this.dataParsed7d);
    }
```

Comment: also don't need holder and adapter.

Answer (score 0):

This is because for setting color you are doing in onBindViewHolder when in that case data would be 0 only without red sign and later you are setting data but after that onBindViewHolder is not called and hence changes are not reflecting.

The way you are doing all this is not ideal way and would suggest you to read design patterns to implement it in proper way.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like. Get value in adapter according to position and change it color like this. Then cocatinate both string and show it. You can test it on multiple devices it will run and show exact in every devices.

```
String status = getColoredSpanned(act.getResources().getString(R.string.order_status),"#3EA7BD");
               String variable_status =getColoredSpanned(act.getResources().getString(R.string.status_order_pending),"#E23941");
               String text = status+variable_status;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    myViewHolder.tv_order_product_status.setText(Html.fromHtml(text,  Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                } else {
                    myViewHolder.tv_order_product_status.setText(Html.fromHtml(text), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                }
```

Comment: wouldn't work because im not using a listView. ;)